# Facebook API - User access token with no expiration

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) that I can get a non-expiring access token for users when calling this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It is obvious what `client_id` and `client_secret` are but what the heck are `grant_type` and `fb_exchange_token`?

I managed to post something to the user's timeline/pin board but as `access_token` I used `APP_ID + | + APP_SECRET`. It worked great.

BTW: I need the permission `manage_pages` because I want to add photos to a user album.

**Any ideas what these two attributes are and where I can get them?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grant type`(the third parameter) is nothing but the string `"fb_exchange_token"`

and

`fb_exchange_token`(the fourth parameter) is the previous `ACCESS_TOKEN` that has either expired or is about to expire.

So for example your requesting URL should be something like :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
client_id=783921075894231403
&client_secret=78789230452234235412793042
&grant_type=fb_exchange_token
&fb_exchange_token=60as98dg690758a0sd5g57869608s9da8g6sda96g5s9adg
```